# Regex Replace in ABAP for replacing multiple characters occurring multiple times?

Tags: abap

This is my string c: Programming is fun, but NOT with ABAP.
The statement I have written is for single character

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '\m' in c WITH '@'.
```

works fine, but how do I replace other single characters using the same statement.

For example: I need to replace 'm', 'i' using one single replace statement. How do I write this, as `REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '\m\p' in c WITH '@'.` is not working

PS: New to ABAP learning.

Comment: Please comment in case you need more explanation, it will be helpful for me, instead of voting to close this question.

Comment: Do you want to replace ocurrences of particular letters?

Comment: Yes like I want to replace all 'm' and 'p' but by using only one REPLACE statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not an ABAP related 'problem' but a question of how to use regex :-)

Try this:

```
DATA: lv_string TYPE string.

lv_string = 'Replace all m, p and s in this string by @'.
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '(m|p|s)' IN lv_string WITH '@'.
WRITE lv_string.
```

Ciao!